# extends Component(react) or extends App(next/app)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im new to nextjs and when I create specific pages in next.js inside ./pages folder, and each specific pages are class-based components, then what we will going to extends?

1. class PageName extends Component {} // from 'react'
2. class PageName extends App {} from 'next/app

I try to extend Component from react and it works where, but the _app.js is useless even i delete it, it doesnt effect the page i created, and if i extend App from next/app it gives me the below error.

> nodeStackFrames.js:39 Uncaught     at loadGetInitialProps (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:3:690)
> at Function.appGetInitialProps (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac.next\server\pages_app.js:156:58)
> at loadGetInitialProps (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
> at Function.appGetInitialProps (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac.next\server\pages_app.js:156:58)
> at loadGetInitialProps (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
> at renderToHTML (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:28:1529)
> at async (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:112:97)
> at async (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:105:142)
> at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:137:387)
> at async DevServer.renderToHTML (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:138:522)
> at async DevServer.renderToHTML (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js:35:578)
> at async DevServer.render (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:75:236)
> at async Object.fn (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:59:580)
> at async Router.execute (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\router.js:25:67)
> at async DevServer.run (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:69:1042)
> at async DevServer.handleRequest (file://C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs-projects\mac\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:34:504)

Answer (score 0):

_app.js is used to overwrite the default app.js, so yes, if you delete it, then your code still works.

You should extend from `React.Component` if you are writing class component.

Comment: thanks for feedback Adam,.. actually i figure out my mistake... these errors exist because i used nextjs Custom Page Extension(https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions) and i set ['page.js'] base extension and I forget to rename _app.js and _document.js to _app.page.js and _document.page.js.